How to diagnose slow connection to server that has high upload speed?
I have an Ubuntu server that upon running the speedtest cli showed ~150mbps upload speeds, however when I connect to a librespeed instance running on the server I get only ~4mbps download speeds from the server. I know it's not my client machine as fast.com shows a 350mbps download, and other servers that I have librespeed running on show me faster speeds. I'm not sure why this specific server is giving such low speeds when in the past (last I checked prior was a few weeks ago) it would give speeds closer to 170mbps. I have no idea where to begin diagnosing this, would anyone have any pointers?

Could it be your client download speed that’s the problem? If not, could it be the MTU on server or client (check, report please). What if the client is on a different network? Ping test from client to server, trace route too to see if its routing between ISPs that’s the problem. I know that from ATT in CA,USA to eu-west-1 in AWS, there is packet loss they haven’t fixed in month for example. I would have posted it as comment but don’t have enough brownie points yet.

I don't think it's the client. Running speedtest on server A (across the country) shows 876 down, 140 up (wired). Speedtest on server B (in my apartment) shows 911 down, 907 up (wired). Fast.com on my client (wireless) shows 480 down and 520 up. I host librespeed instances on both servers, and running those from my client gives 3.89 down/191 up from server A and 321 down/192 up from server B (all speeds are in mbps). So it seems clear that it's an issue with the connection from client to server A (unless my ISP for server A is throttling me?)

Ok so it’s just client->serverA. Are you able to test the client going through a VPN or putting the client on another network? It would isolate if it’s the clients networking or network between client and server. Also check another client (on a different network) to that server. Then you will know if its server networking (just because speed test.net works doesn’t mean it isn’t), client networking or somewhere between this client and server and which ISP (client or server) is at fault. Way of exclusion.

So I had some friends in different states try it out and they all saw much lower download speeds than upload speeds (highest download anyone got was 24.2 mbps despite speedtest from the server showing 150mbps). Could it possibly be router settings affecting this?

So server or its router or its ISP are at fault. Can you test the server from the same network? And test from the server to itself? Then you’ll know if it’s router, ISP or server itself.

So I just tested from the same network and got some interesting results. The client machine I'm using got 250 mbps down, 98 up from fast.com (I'm using this as the effective speed of the wifi adapter on this client). Running the speedtest on my server using it's DNS name (so would route through cloudflare and public internet) I get 40 down, 8 up. But connecting directly to the speedtest via local IP and port, I get 249 down and 121 up. So I think that rules out the server and the router being the source of the issue?

Yes, that's pretty much a cloudflare issue or otherwise the ISP.

Seems the issue is with Cloudflare, as I did one more test. domain.name.for.speedtest gave me 111 down/30 up, localip:port gave 216 down/179 up, and publicip:port gave 240 down/120 up (with 240 down/96 up as the benchmark from fast.com). I guess I'll move this discussion over to the cloudflare support forums, thanks!
